# How do I iterate over Stickers.xcassets or get images from xcassets?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a custom sticker app extension and I want to loop through my Sticker.xcassets folder instead of setting up a fixed for loop.

For example:

```
func getStickers() {

    for index in 1...16 {
        addSticker(location: "\(index)", description: "\(index)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably aware that you do not access the files within your project folder using string literal paths. Instead you use the functions provided by NSBundle. Happily, these include functions that will do what you are looking for. Looking at the developer reference for NSBundle at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html

The listing I think you want from this document is 3-11, which describes how to pull all the assets of a given type from the bundle:

```
CFArrayRef  birdURLs;

// Find all of the JPEG images in a given directory.
birdURLs = CFBundleCopyResourceURLsOfType( mainBundle,
                CFSTR("jpg"),
                CFSTR("BirdImages") );
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Conceptually I get it but how would I do this in Swift? I've tried adapting the code to work within my project and it spits out lots of fun errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access programmatically a .xcassets file at runtime. I'm also working on a similar task, the solution I came up is very simple. Images are named using following convention: imageNameAndIdentifier (for example: heart0, heart1, heart2, etc). Using a loop where the full name of the image is constructed and an UIImage is created, I get all the needed images.

```
    let stickerName = "heart"
    var images = [UIImage]()
    var lastImageIndex = 0

    lastImageIndex = lastStickerImageIndex(name: stickerName)

    for index in 0...lastImageIndex {
        images.append(UIImage.init(named: stickerName + "\(index)"))
    }
```

Pay attention to `lastImageIndex` variable. It's value is calculated based on number of files which contains in filename a given string and substracting one unit, because last index is = (length_of_array - 1).

```
private func lastStickerImageIndex(name: String) -> Int {
    return (FileManager.default.numberOfFilesWhichNameContains(string: name) - 1)
}
```

I've created an extension which returns number of files based on a string which should be contained in the desired file name.

```
extension FileManager {

    func numberOfFilesWhichNameContains(string: String) -> Int {

        do {
            let bundleFiles = try self.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: Bundle.main.bundlePath)
            let filteredBundleFiles = bundleFiles.filter({
                $0.contains(string)
            })

            return filteredBundleFiles.count

        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }

        return 0
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go and let you know what happens. Cheers

Comment: Hey there, trying your code and getting "Use of unresolved identifier 'name'. Is that something that should be passed in through a function?

Comment: Is this available in a public repo or gist? Thanks!

Comment: 'name' is the sequence name. For example if your sequence is named: heart0, heart1, heart2, etc. then 'name' must be 'heart'

Comment: Gotcha, could you update your code to reflect how this would be used?

Answer (score 0):

Grab all of your stickers, put them in a folder, then rename it to stickers.bundle, now you can put it inside you xcode project. Just drag the folder to your project files in xcode, make sure to marke

`[X] Copy items if needed` and `Create folder references`

[image]

```swift
 
   func retriveStickers() -> [UIImage] {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let bundleURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL
        let assetURL = bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("stickers.bundle")
        var stickerImageList = [UIImage]()
        
        do {
            let contents = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: assetURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: [URLResourceKey.nameKey, URLResourceKey.isDirectoryKey], options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
         
//contents will be a list of strings with the full path of your stickers:
//file:///Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/.../appname.app/stickers.bundle/funSticker.png   
            for item in contents {

//here we use item.lastPathComponent (funSticker.png) to get only the sticker name, so we can use it in an UIImage.
                stickerImageList.append(UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: item.lastPathComponent))
            }
            
        } catch let error as NSError {
//handle errors
            print(error)
        }
        
        return stickerImageList
    }
```